# Не получается применить метод sendPhoto

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Делаю бота в телеграм, использую telegram-bot-api, есть нижеследующий код. Работает так: при нажатии на кнопку "Пример" бот отправляет сообщение с текстом и с инлайн клавиатурой.

```
if(message.text == 'Пример') { 
    return message.send(`Текст в сообщении`, {
        parse_mode: "HTML",
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{ text: "Кнопка на клавиатуре", callback_data: "button" }]
            ]
        }
    });
}
```

Хочу сделать так, чтобы к сообщению прикреплялась картинка. Картинку я загрузил на свой хост в корневую папку. Изменяю код следующим образом:

```
if(message.text == 'Пример') { 
    return bot.sendPhoto(message.chat.id, `picture.jpg`, { caption: `Текст в сообщении.`, {
        parse_mode: "HTML",
        reply_markup: {
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{ text: "Кнопка на клавиатуре", callback_data: "button" }]
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

}

После этого бот не реагирует на нажатия любых кнопок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так сделал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил самостоятельно. Была лишняя фигурная скобка перед parse_mode